# Prove the correctness and continuity of function

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

Let $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is continuous function $f_n:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let's suppose that sequence $\sum_{n\ge 1}\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f_n(x)|$ converges.

Show that the function $f(x) := \sum_{n\ge1}f_n(x)$ is correctly stated and that it is continuous on $[a, b]$

Please, can you give me a hint how to start the solution and I don't quite understand what means "to prove that function is correctly stated"

Edit: Ok, I can prove that it is correctly stated (the proof of it is exactly like @avs's answer. What about continuity? I think that I should prove that $\int_a^bf(x)$ is continuous

Comment: "Is correctly stated" in this case means "is well-defined". So you must prove that $\lim_{m \to \infty} S_m(x)$ exists for every $x$ where $S_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m f_n(x)$.

Comment: @EricThoma I think I can prove that $\lim_{m->\infty}S_m(x)$ exists (I will edit the question with my effort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $x \in [a, b]$, the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} |f_{n}(x)|$ is majorized by the convergent series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \max_{[a, b]} |f_{n}|$, hence converges.

Therefore, the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} f_{n}(x)$ **converges absolutely**.  Therefore, by the completeness of ${\mathbb R}$ in the metric induced by $| \cdot |$, the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} f_{n}(x)$ converges.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I was writing now, thank you so much! I think it now does not make sense to edit question with this proof, but I should prove that now this function continuous

Comment: Cauchy criterion to the rescue.:)  Using the notation of @Eric Thoma, with $n > m$, for *all* $x \in [a, b]$ we have:
$$
S_{n}(x) - S_{m}(x) = \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} f_{k}(x) \leq  \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} \max_{[a, b]} |f_{k}|.
$$
Notice that the right-hand side of the inequality does not depend on $x$.  Which should help a lot.:)

Comment: I should prove that right-hand side is no more that $\varepsilon$ and it is true for big m, because thing on the right-hand converges then it has finite sum, so I can find such m that $\sum_{k = m+1}^n\max_{[a, b]}|f_k|$ no more then $\varepsilon$?